# Data structure to keep count of elements and retrieve elements with count within range

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I need a data structure to keep count of elements and then retrieve elements within a certain range of counts.

Example:

```
counter = RangeCounter()
for el in [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0]
    counter.add(el)

counter.get(occurence >= 1 and occurence <= 2)
>>> 1, 2 (element 1 is encountered 2 times)
>>> 2, 3 (element 2 in encountered 3 times)
```

Comment: Have you tried to solve the problem yourself? If so, how far have you gotten? If not, what potential approaches come to mind?

Comment: Have you tried extending ``collections.Counter``?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) you could do all that:

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter([1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0])
# Counter({2: 3, 1: 2, 0: 1})

# occurence >= 1 and occurence <= 2
res = {item: count for item, count in counter.items() if 1 <= count <= 2}
# {1: 2, 0: 1}
```